# Random parameters generation in googletest parameter tests

Tags: c++, testing, random, googletest

I want to generate some random values for my parametrized googletest tests. Here two problems occur:

1. I want to use built-in C++ rand() function, but generated numbers repeats in all tests. Then, I tried to use `GetParam()` as seed, but I have problems with assigning the value returned by this function to srand() function. It is attached to question with the necessity to make const to non-const cast, I use different variants of static_cast, and const_cast from const int to long int*, but none has been even compiled.
2. Maybe there is a built-in function in Google Tests for generating a random set of variables used for tests? I dig through documentation, but there is hardly anything about that.

Comment: Please make sure to include the relevant code in your question. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and **especially** [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

1) [According to CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand) `srand()` expects an `unsigned` as parameter. Are you using `unsigned` as the parameter type for your parametrized tests? (Sidenote: here seeing the code that gives you trouble would have been **really** useful...)

2) Not to my knowledge. But there is nothing that keeps you from using an ordinary int as Type-Parameter, and feed that into a function that generates a pseudo-random value from it.